# Week between two dates Java + Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I wanted to get the number of weeks and months between two date range in Java. For ex., 
Start Date: 03/01/2012
End Date:   03/05/2012

Since the two dates fall in two different weeks I want the result to be 2 instead of 0.

Second part of the problem is: 
Start Date: 02/29/2012
End Date: 03/01/2012

Number of months in between should be 2.

I have been searching online regarding this and lot of people have recommended using Joda Date time in Java. So I gave it a shot. I was able to get the weeks working but I am not sure if this is the right way. Here is what I am doing to get the week duration:

```
    DateTime s = new DateTime(Long.parseLong("1330573027000")); // 2012-02-29
    DateTime e = new DateTime(Long.parseLong("1331005027000")); // 2012-03-05   

    Weeks weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(s, e).plus(1);
```

This returns 1, when I am expecting 2 since two dates are in different weeks.

For months duration I tried to follow the same but it returns 0 but I want it to return 2 since the two dates are in two different months.

Could someone please point me in right direction?

Thanks!

**Edit:** 
I think I got one way of doing it, please let me know if it looks right:

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime(Long.parseLong("1330659427000"));
    DateTime start = new DateTime(Long.parseLong("1331005027000"));

    DateTime finalStart = start.dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue();
    DateTime finalEnd   = end.dayOfWeek().withMaximumValue();
```

And then get the difference between finalStart and finalEnd. Does this looks correct?

**Edit2** 
Updated the end time

Comment: two different weeks? what if the dates are say, `2012-02-29` and `2012-12-29`, satisfies two different weeks? you looking at answer=2, for above as well?

Comment: No, in the scenario you have listed it should count the number of weeks between the two date ranges. So what I am essentially wanting to do is get the duration between first day of start date's week and last day of end date's week. That way I will get 2 and not the duration just between the two dates.

Comment: in your example, the weeks are not in two different weeks, `2012-02-29` and `2012-03-01` belong to the same week! your requirement is not clear!

Comment: >in the scenario you have listed it should count the number of weeks >between the two date ranges.


try this then, 

 `Weeks weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween( new DateTime().withDate(2012,    02, 29),  new DateTime().withDate(2012, 12, 29));

Comment: Yep, my bad I have updated the end time in the OP.

Comment: weeksBetween(new DateTime().withDate(2012, 02, 29), new DateTime().withDate(2012, 03, 05)); will not return me the desired value.

Comment: check my answer based on that you want!

Answer (score 7):

JodaTime Weeks.weeksBetween(s, e) returns only whole week count. Incomplete weeks are not counted. To resolve this, you must garantee that the days are at the start and at the end of the week.
Try this:

```
int weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(s.dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue().minusDays(1), 
            e.dayOfWeek().withMaximumValue().plusDays(1)).getWeeks();
```

The minusDays/plusDays will garantee that the weeks i'm trying to count are full.

Same logic apply for Months:

```
int months = Months.monthsBetween(s.dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue().minusDays(1),
             e.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue().plusDays(1)).getMonths();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int OFFSET_ONE = 1;

    DateTime t1 = new DateTime().withDate(2012, 02, 29).withDayOfWeek(1);
    DateTime t2 = new DateTime().withDate(2012, 03, 05).withDayOfWeek(7);

    int week1 = t2.weekOfWeekyear().get(); 
    int week2 = t1.weekOfWeekyear().get();

    System.out.println(week1-week2+OFFSET_ONE); // add OFFSET_ONE
```

does it give what you are after?

Comment: I think it does but how is it different from what I was doing which is:                                                

    `DateTime s = new DateTime(Long.parseLong("1330659427000"));`
    `DateTime e = new DateTime(Long.parseLong("1330832227000"));` 
    `DateTime fs = s.dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue();`
    `DateTime fe = e.dayOfWeek().withMaximumValue();`
    `Weeks weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(fs, fe).plus(1);`

Comment: looks OK! but its a very strange requirement! is all i can say!